# Error:Array bound is not an integer

Tags: c++

```
main()
{
int n;
cout<<"Enter integer n";
cin>>n;
double arr[n][n];
double func(double array[n][n]);
func(arr);
}
```

I understand that at compile time 'n' is not initialized.But what can I do to take 'n' as input from user's end,yet pass the array to 'func' as in the above code.

Comment: I suggest that you find tutorials on how to program in c++ on the net. In those you should look for pointers to arrays, how to allocate an array to such a pointer and how to pass a pointer to a function. The size of the array that pointer points to can be apssed along with the pointer.

Comment: what's your platform? if you are on linux it's ok otherwise if you're on windows you can't, you should use pointers to arrays

Comment: @Raindrop7 This has nothing to do with the operating system.

Comment: @melpomene I mean the compilers of windows. I've already faced such problem

Comment: Windows doesn't come with a compiler. I'm using gcc on windows right now.